# Importing excel xlsx data using XLconnect and readWorksheet causes incorrect format

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xlconnect

I have a Excel file with the extension xlsx where Sheet1 and Sheet contains the following: 18:20, 10:10 (column A, row 1:2). When I try to import them into R I do not get expected results.

```
library(XLConnect)

setwd("...")
my_book <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx")

xlsx_import <- lapply(getSheets(my_book), readWorksheet, object = my_book) 
xlsx_import


# Returns some kind of date format

xlsx_import <- lapply(getSheets(my_book), readWorksheet, object = my_book, colTypes = "character")
xlsx_import


# Same as above
```

Is it possible to fix  this in R somehow? As I have quite a lot of sheets to go through.

Comment: I would guess the problem is that Excel is thinking that these cells are times, so it will export them in date/time format. If they are held in Excel as dates, then your best option might be to import them into R as you are doing, and then try to extract the data, rather than doing it via `readWorksheet` options.

Comment: After you import the data, try something like this `df$problem.column <- format(df$problem.column, format = "%H:%M")`

Comment: did not work...

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This.

wb=loadWorkbook("Test.xlsx", create = TRUE)

setStyleAction(wb, XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.DATATYPE")
cs = createCellStyle(wb, name = "myDateStyle")
setDataFormat(cs, format = "dd-mm-yyyy")
setCellStyleForType(wb, style = cs, type = XLC$"DATA_TYPE.DATETIME")



s<-readWorksheet(wb,sheet = "Sheet1")

***Operations which you wanna do***

writeWorksheet(wb, wq, sheet = "Sheet1")
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb,"*",TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: Some additional information about this code only answer would probably be beneficial.